# HTML5 way of invoking parent JavaScript function from iFrame -- besides using postMessage? Or solution for PhoneGap apps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, postmessage

We're aware of cross-domain limitations imposed on inter-window communication and the introduction of **postMessage** in HTML5.

However, we're wondering if there are other ways an iFrame could invoke JavaScript functions defined in its parent window.

We find **postMessage** a little clunky for invoking multiple methods, which each require multiple parameters.

If no HTML5 alternatives exist, bonus points for offering a solution in PhoneGap.

PhoneGap details here:

We embed an iFrame in the PhoneGap "index.html" page.

From "index.html," we can invoke JavaScript functions or access variables in the iFrame.

But we cannot invoke functions or access variables in "index.html" from the iFrame.

Is there something about PhoneGap that prevents this from working in reverse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to postMessage is a URL hashtag change. It's not difficult to encode more complicated messages in a JSON message and encode / decode the text:

{"methodName": ['a', 'b', 3]}

Becomes: #%7B%22methodName%22%3A%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%203%5D%7D

If you have a script on the other side watching for hash change and processing the messages, you're good to go.

Note that the same trick can work just fine with postMessage in browsers that support it. A popular way to do this is to use postMessage and fall back on hash change.

Answer (score 0):

`parent.funcitonName(args);` works just fine for me. I'm not sure if there's cross-domain issues though, I do all my iFrame code on one domain.

Comment: What's odd is that in PhoneGap, I can call functions in the iFrame, but the iFrame cannot call functions in the parent. May be specific to PhoneGap?

Comment: It's not specific to PhoneGap. It's a security measure built into browsers to prevent guest iFrames from contaminating parent code.

I suspect what you're seeing is the same-origin policy.